# iOS and continuous integration over network?

Tags: ios, macos, networking

Please bear with me - I've never really used a Mac for more than a few hours at a time.

If I have a somewhat new Mac with OS X and Xcode setup in my network, would it be possible for me to push code to it to build/compile iOS apps, from non-OSX computers?

Thanks

Comment: What sort of code are you compiling on the Mac? If you need the Xcode environment, you might want to configure the Mac for VNC, get a VNC client for your desktop computer, and then remote into the Mac to work at the Mac from your current computer. Or there are lots of different tools to access your Mac's desktop from a PC. If you google it, you'll see lots of alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) on a mac. When I push code to the repository on github it is notified by github about the changes. Hudson will then pull the new code and build it using the xcodebuild command. Afterwards the app is uploaded to [testflightapp](https://testflightapp.com/).

Does that sound like what you mean when you say "push code to it" ?